# How do I use JavaScript for number formatting?

Tags: javascript, regex, formatting, numbers, isnumeric

I want to use JavaScript to restrict input on a text box to currency number formatting. For example:

```
<input type="text" value="2,500.00" name="rate" />
```

As given above, the text box should accept only numbers, commas and a period.

But, after the period it should accept two digits after numbers.

How do I accomplish this? Please clarify.

- Gnaniyar Zubair

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[parseFloat](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Functions/ParseFloat) can convert a string to a float and [toFixed](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed) can set how many decimal places to keep.

```
function numToCurrency(num){
    return parseFloat(num).toFixed(2);
}


numToCurrency("4.2334546") // returns 4.23
```

Comment: Hi Zech,

Thanks for your instance coding. i will try it out.

- Gnaniyar Zubair

Comment: This actually doesn't do what your question originally intended... but could be merged into a more complete answer. I'll leave it up if it's useful.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do validation for your textbox, you can use [Regular Expressions](http://www.evolt.org/article/Regular_Expressions_in_JavaScript/17/36435/). If you want to restrict the input from the user, you can trap the keystrokes and filter out the ones you want them to enter using the [onKeyDown](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_onkeydown.asp) event of the textbox.

Comment: Hi Kirtan,

Thanks for your immediate response. i will try it out

Answer (score 0):

These jQuery plugins can help..

http://www.texotela.co.uk/code/jquery/numeric/

http://plugins.jquery.com/project/aphanumeric

Comment: Hi Vijay,

Thanks for your spontaneous response. i will try it out

- Gnaniyar Zubair

Answer (score 0):

You could use a [jQuery](http://jqueryui.com/home)'s plugin called [Alphanumeric](http://itgroup.com.ph/alphanumeric/)

> jQuery AlphaNumeric is a javascript
>   control plugin that allows you to
>   limit what characters a user can enter
>   on textboxes or textareas. Have fun.